# Passing ID from url to MVC Controller (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to AngularJS, trying to pass the ID from the url to MVC controller JSON method and then return the JSON to the angular scope.

Here is my MVC Controller:

```
public ActionResult Client(int clientid)
{
    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetClient(string clientid)
{   

    ClientDao clientDao = new ClientDao();

    Client client = clientDao.getClientById(int.Parse(clientid));

    return new JsonResult { Data = client, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

And here is my Angular .js file:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Home/Client/:clientid', {
            controller: 'ClientCtrl'
        })
         .otherwise({
             redirectTo: "/Home/Index"
         })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
});

app.controller("ClientCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    // alert($routeParams.clientid);
$http({
    url: "/Home/GetClient/",
    params: {clientid: $routeParams.clientid},
    method: "get"   
})
    .then (function (response) {
        $scope.client = response.data;
    })
});
```

The problem is that the parameter `clientid` in the `$routeParams` is always undefined. How should I fix this ?

Update: Here's how my link looks like: http://something.com/Home/Client/20

Comment: I think you are asking for trouble by having both the asp.net mvc route and the angular route pointing at the same location (/Home/Client).  Is this not a SPA application?

Comment: Yes, at the end, it should be. I'm new to this stuff anyway, so I'm trying to figure out how to pass that ID to the server, get the JSON response, and repass that response to the scope.

Answer (score 1):

The way you defined your action in the MVC controller, assuming that the default Route is the only one defined, it expects your url to look like http://something.com/Home/Client?clientid=20

Solutions:

1. Rename clientId to id
2. Add another route in AppStart/RouteConfig that has a clientid param
3. Use attribute routing and define your route like [Route("getclient/{clientid}")]

Comment: I'm able to acess the `JsonResult GetClient(string clientid)`, however the `clientid` is always null and here is the problem. If I give the string a static value, my code works.